# Is it possible to export using nuiton-csv into a Reader or InputStream?

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv

I'd like to export some data using [nuiton-csv](https://forge.nuiton.org/projects/nuiton-csv) into a Reader ou  InputSream, is there a simple way to do this ?

The main purpose is to expose the export as a stream for another process (download for example, zip, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not actually: all data are consumed into a writer.

But, something has been done here : https://forge.nuiton.org/issues/3790.

Will come soon out of the box.

Comment: Next version will bring this in,and before new year! Enjoy.